# Java Logging - logging is done, where is my log file

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, glassfish, java.util.logging

I am using java.util.logging, NetBeans IDE and Glassfish Server.

I have loaded a custom log properties file. Application is doing the logging but the log file is missing.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

is my logfile properties and following is the code to load it:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceInvoker.class.getName());
log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("log.properties");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
props.load(fis);
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(fis);
```

I checked for the log file at location C:\Users\user_name.
When I don't use this logging, I can see the log messages in NetBeans server console, when I use this logging there is no message in console and also the log file is missing! Please help.

Comment: did you give the absolute path?

Comment: no, 
for properties: classLoader.getResource("log.properties");
for logfile: java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log

Comment: Try `System.out.println(System.get("user.home"));`. It must be in that location. Also try giving an absolute path in place of `%h` if that does not work

Comment: My mistake. The issue is, before loading in LogManager, I have loaded the property file and then I again try to load the same. Thanks Raze2dust for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("log.properties");
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);
```

is the right code.